# PHP: Update child when parent changes

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Does anybody knows an editor or an easy way to accomplish this:

```
class A{

public function __construct($a){
      //Do something 
    }

}

Class B extends A{

public function __construct($a,$b){
         parent::__construct($a);
         //DO something with $b
    }
}
```

Let's suppose I've update the __construct in the A class, adding a second parameter.

```
class A{

    public function __construct($a,$c){
          //Do something 
        }

    }
```

Is there any IDE that will automatically update all childs from my A class in order to update the __construct method?

```
Class B extends A{

public function __construct($a,$b,$c){
         parent::__construct($a,$c);
         //DO something with $b
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHPStorm IDE** you mentioned in the tags can do this. Just make sure you make use of the **Refactor** tool (**Refactor > Change** signature in your case) - adding the parameter manually in the ccode won't have any results on the children.